# Where to place add_action when enqueueing?

Tags: actions, wp-enqueue-script

Do I place `add_action` before or after `function myTheme_script {enqueue functions here}` when enqueueing a script or stylesheet into functions.php, or does it matter? I'm seeing both from moderators on WP forums.

So...

```
function profondo_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfifteen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'profondo-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'profondo_scripts' );
```

or...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'profondo_scripts' );

function profondo_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfifteen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'profondo-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
```

Comment: Does not matter what so ever. At least from what I've seen. Others do it the other way and others the other. I like to put the add_action after the function so I "know" that I have already declared the function before calling it. But works both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes no difference. Despite the fact `add_action` doesn't actually check if the callback is indeed callable (i.e. is a valid function/class/method), PHP will first "load" function and class definitions before executing inline code, hence why you can do something like:

```
wpse_185390_function(); // Perfectly fine, even though the function is defined "afterwards"

function wpse_185390_function() {
    echo 'I\'m down here!';
}
```

It's entirely up to you if you "hook" before or after the definition - I personally prefer after for consistency (it's how pretty much all WordPress core does it).